# Pythonic way to sum vertically and horizontally a dictionary of list

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict = {1:[1,2,3,4],2:[5,5,5,3],3:[5,6,7,8]}
```

I have seen a pythonic way to sum each list of the dictionary, but is there a pythonic way to sum all corresponding elements of the lists in the dictionary?

```
E.g.:
1+5+5 are the first elements of all the lists
2+5+6 are the second elements of all the lists
```

Currently I am using a double for loop.

Comment: What have you tried, and what is insufficiently pythonic about it

Comment: A for double loop. Its ugly

Comment: @Erosennin hello, could you let me know why you have unaccepted my answer? How can I improve it so it solves your problem?

Comment: Sorry, did not mean to, browser issues/lag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't really care about the order in which items are added you can just use `zip` on `dict.values` in a list comprehension:

```
d = {1:[1,2,3,4],2:[5,5,5,3],3:[5,6,7,8]}

print([sum(i) for i in zip(*d.values())])
```

Output:

```
[11, 13, 15, 15]
```